# Exclude whitespace in regex but kep underscore and hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I've variable which are delimited by "$" and can contains dot, hyphen and underscore in any order but no whitespace.
Actually my regex is:

```
"\\$(.*?)\\$"
```

But it doesn't work with that case for exemple:

> I loose 12$ but you loose 25$

The result is "$ but you loose 25$".

I also tried with:

```
"\\$\\w+\\$"
```

But now, it doesn't work with hyphen

Add more details:

I want only match exepression with 0 or more dot-underscore-hyphen like that:

> $test_underscore$
>
> $test-hyphen$
>
> $test$
>
> $test_test2-test3$
>
> $test.test2-test3$

and nothing if there is a whitespace like my first exemple

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a negated character class matching any char but whitespace and dollar:

```
"\\$[^\\s$]+\\$"
```

Here, `\$` matches a literal dollar symbol, that can be followed with one or more symbols other than whitespace and a dollar symbol, followed with another dollar symbol.

To match word chars, dots and hyphens only in between the dollars, use a white list approach:

```
"\\$[\\w.-]+\\$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\S*)\\$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

`\S*` means anything but whitespace

Comment: However, it will also match `$str$$str2$` as one entry while it contains two.